# Add new item to Object Array

Tags: vb.net

I have an object array containing objects with arrays. When i try to add another object later i get an error saying

```
'An exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in     
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Public member 'Add' on type 'Object()()' not found.'
```

And here is how i try to add new member

```
Dim data As Object = {
                   New Object() {"Year", "Sales", "Expenses"},
                   New Object() {"2004", 1000, 400},
                   New Object() {"2005", 1170, 460},
                   New Object() {"2006", 660, 1120},
                   New Object() {"2007", 1030, 540}
              }

Dim newObj = New Object() {"2008", 1030, 540}
data.Add(newObj)  'here the error occures
```

I tried changing data to List(of Object) and then it worked but the format of List is not acceptable later (i send data to different api as json).

Probably it's easy issue but i'am kind of newbie :) Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `data` is an `Object`. `Object` has no `Add` method. But since you actually declare it as `Object()`(an array of objects) you cannot use `Add` either because an array has a fixed size.

Instead use a `List(Of Object)` which can be resized:

```
Dim data As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object) From
{
       New Object() {"Year", "Sales", "Expenses"},
       New Object() {"2004", 1000, 400},
       New Object() {"2005", 1170, 460},
       New Object() {"2006", 660, 1120},
       New Object() {"2007", 1030, 540}
}
// ...
data.Add(newObj)
```

However, why do you use objects at all if you want to store strings? I would declare it as `List(Of String)`, otherwise you always need to unbox to the same type that was boxed which is inefficient, less readable and more error-prone.

If you need an `Object()` you can use `data.ToArray()` when you're finished with it.

Comment: yeah i said earlier that the list wasn't accepted by the api but after some tweaking i managed to get this working :)

Comment: @JakubWisniewski: you can always use `data.ToArray()` to create the final array from the list.