# Implementing add method for array-type property in custom class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I'm creating a class called Job with a property called Tasks. Tasks is an array of the type Task (another class). I can return the Tasks collection using a public readonly property that returns the array, but how do I implement an add method to add a task to Tasks?

I started with a simple class and researched [Write Own "Add" Method For An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013218/write-own-add-method-for-an-array) and [Add new item to Object Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010120/add-new-item-to-object-array) and many others. I have an inherent mistake in my thinking and I do not know the right terms to find the correct solution.

```
Public Class Job
    Private _taskcount As Integer
    Private _tasks() As Task
    Public ReadOnly Property TaskCount
        Get
            Return _taskcount
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Tasks As Task()
        Get
            Return tasks
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

I would love to be able to `dim myjob as new job` and then do `myjob.tasks.add`, but I do not have an idea where in the class definition the Add method goes. Help with adding the Add method would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I also understand that the property TaskCount should be implemented as `Tasks.Count`. So my underlying problem is the implementation of properties and methods of a property.

Comment: Use the class contructor to set both.

Comment: Don't use an array.  Use a collection and then you get the `Add` method for free.  It would be `List(Of Task)` or perhaps `Collection(Of Task)`.

Comment: Dont cache the `_taskcount`

Comment: jmcilhinney: thank you. Excellent idea and helped me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to write your class, guarding your `List` while exposing it as an `IEnumerable`

```
Public Class Job
    Private _tasks As New List(Of Task)
    Public ReadOnly Property TaskCount As Integer
        Get
            Return _tasks.Count
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Tasks As IEnumerable(Of Task)
        Get
            Return _tasks
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub AddTask(t As Task)
        _tasks.Add(t)
    End Sub
End Class
```

We don't need to cache the task count since your list has a Count property.

Also I don't see the need to the property TaskCount because you can just get it from `myJob.Tasks.Count`. The property could [read: should] be removed.

Now, you also mentioned you would like to be able to do `Dim myJob As New Job()` and then do `myJob.Tasks.Add`. You could expose the list publicly like below, making `Tasks` ReadOnly.

```
Public Class Job
    Public ReadOnly Property Tasks As New List(Of Task)
End Class
```

Now anyone can do `Dim myJob As New Job()` and then do `myJob.Tasks.Add` and since Tasks is ReadOnly nobody can reassign it (I mean NOBODY, even inside the class (outside the constructor!)...). But now you can access all the properties and methods of `List`

There is no right answer without knowing your specific requirements. But there is a lot of discussion on the topic. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/387973/832052 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/400144/832052

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me enormously and pointed out my mistake in thinking I should use an array instead of a list.